# How to get two divs to sit side by side, hiding overflow if the container is too narrow

Tags: css, html

I'm trying to get two divs always side-by-side even when the container is too small. I want to hide the overflow of the righthand div, but can't seem to achieve this. When I resize the browser to make the scrollbar appear on the body, the right-hand div moves down underneath.

Here's my HTML so far:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    min-width: 800px; overflow: auto;
}       

span { display: block; }

#div-outer {
    width: 95%;
    height: 300px;
    padding: 2px;
    border: 4px solid green;
    display: block;
}

#div-box-left {
    border: 3px solid black;
    width: 250px;
    height: 250px;
    float: left;
    display: inline-block;
}

#div-box-right {
    border: 3px solid red;
    height: 250px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    overflow: hidden;
    float: left;
    display: inline-block;
}

#tbl {
    background: yellow;
    border: 3px solid blue;
}

        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <span>Wide div to contains two divs</span>
        <div id="div-outer">
            <div id="div-box-left">
                Left div with a width of 250px
            </div>
            <div id="div-box-right">
                <span>This contains a table but is too wide to fix - I want the table's overflow hidden</span>
                <table id="tbl">
                    <tr>
                        <td>Column</td>
                        <td>Column</td>
                        <td>Column</td>
                        <td>Column</td>
                        <td>Column</td>
                        <td>Column</td>
                        <td>Column</td>
                        <td>Column</td>
                        <td>Column</td>
                        <td>Column</td>
                        <td>Column</td>
                        <td>Column</td>
                        <td>Column</td>
                        <td>Column</td>
                        <td>Column</td>
                        <td>Column</td>
                        <td>Column</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may need another `div`, alternatively you could apply the style for `.outer` on the body:

[Simplified example](http://jsfiddle.net/XrHK7/)

CSS:

```
.outer{width: 600px; overflow:hidden; border:2px solid lightblue; padding:10px;}
.innerwrap{width:9999px;}
.inner{width:400px; height:200px; border:2px solid salmon; float:left;}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="outer">
<div class="innerwrap">
    <div class="inner"></div>
    <div class="inner"></div>
</div>
```

[**Your example, fixed.**](http://jsfiddle.net/XrHK7/1/)

Answer (score 1):

Reorder your `divs`:

```
<div id="div-outer">
  <div id="div-box-right"><div>
    ...
  </div></div>
  <div id="div-box-left">
    ...
  </div>
</div>
```

and change css:

```
#div-box-left {
  border: 3px solid black;
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
  float: left;
  margin-left: -100%;
}
#div-box-right {
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
}
#div-box-right > div {
  border: 3px solid red;
  height: 250px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin-left: 260px;
}
```

You can see this working [here](http://jsfiddle.net/brettwp/4TBrk/).

Answer (score 1):

I found this below code very useful, maybe it will help anyone who comes searching and wants a quick result -

```
<html>
<body>
    <div style="width: 50%; height: 50%; background-color: green; float:left;"></div>
    <div style="width: 50%; height: 50%; background-color: blue; float:right;"></div>
    <div style="width: 100%; height: 50%; background-color: red; clear:both"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old post, but the best way to do this now is to use the display property of flex. All styling besides the display property is just to illustrate the placement of the divs.

```html
<div id="div-outer">
  <div id="div-box-right">
    ...
  </div>
  <div id="div-box-left">
    ...
  </div>
</div>
<style>
  #div-outer {
    display: flex;
    border: thin solid red;
  }
  
  #div-outer div {
    border: thin solid black;
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    margin: 5%;
  }
</style>
```